# Regular expression search between curly braces

Tags: javascript, regex, search

I have a massive array, over 40,000 items - rather than looping over each item, and checking each property, I wanted to first serialize the massive array as a string.

And then write a simple regular expression to match between two of the properties in the object.

In EVERY single object, they all start with a key of 'aaa' and value of true.

There's a variety of key-value pairs that can follow, then the last key-value pair on the object is `zzz: true`.

```
var data = JSON.stringify([{
    aaa: true,
    some: 'cat goes meow',
    zzz: true
},{
    aaa: true,
    some: 'dog goes woof',
    zzz: true
}]);
```

I basically want to have a search term "dog", and have a regular expression return me from `aaa` to `zzz` where any of the values between these keys match the query `dog`, in the above example I'd expect to get the last item from the array.

What I've tried: https://regex101.com/r/yNSTs9/2

Comment: Why don't you instead use JavaScript to parse your JSON into an object, and then traverse it using dot notation?  Wouldn't that be easier than using a regex?

Comment: Because it will take way too long, and it's a multi dimensional array too @tim

Comment: You say *In EVERY single object, they all start with a key of 'aaa' and value of true.*  But objects don't guarantee property order do they?

Comment: Why would it be faster to execute a regex on a huge string - huge collection of characters - than iterating over fewer objects? That could be slower as well. Did you try to build an index or inserting your objects in a smarter data structure?

Answer (score 1):

I have converted your array into string and try to find data as you want.

check below regex

```
regex - /([^\}\{])([^\}\{]*)(dog)([^\}\{]*)(\})/g
```

```js
var results = '[{"aaa":true,"some":"cat goes meow","zzz":true},{"aaa":true,"some":"dog goes woof","zzz":true}]'.match(/([^\}\{])([^\}\{]*)(dog)([^\}\{]*)(\})/g);

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern `aaa.+(?=[^}]*dog[^}]*)[^}]+`.

Explanation:

`aaa.+` matches `aaa` and at least one of any character, until `(?=[^}]*dog[^}]*)`, which means position, which preceeds any string containing `dog` **BUT** not containing `}`, so we don't jump over to next object (thanks to `[^}]`). If assertion is true (positive lookahead matches), then match everything until `}`: `[^}]+`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yNSTs9/3)